# How to find quotes with double quotes?

Tags: jquery

my english language is not good. sorry!

How to write quotes with double quotes inside the one var?

i want merge two script: number1 and number2

```js
//number 1:
    var rew = /\'/g;
    $('span').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3 && rew.test(this.nodeValue)) {
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(rew, '');
    }
    });
    
 //number 2:
    var ref = /\"/g;
    $('span').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3 && ref.test(this.nodeValue)) {
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(ref, '');
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
Hello 'world'.<br>
Hello "world".
</span>
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of an input and the expected output? There isn't enough information in the question to be able to determine what you're trying to do

Comment: @CertainPerformance i want find quotes with double quotes and replace to None inside the span.

Comment: Please edit a concrete example into your question. Remember, questions should contain a [MCVE]

Comment: @CertainPerformance I edited my question. sorry my English language is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand, you could simply include both `'` and `"` in a character set:

```
/['"]/g
```

This will match and remove all quotemarks. But this will also remove quotemarks that aren't actually quoting, eg:

```
Bob's
games' difficulty
```

So you may consider matching only quotemarks that have a matching quotemark later, before a word break. Match *and capture* a `'` or a `"`, then repeat and capture (in a second capturing group) any non-space characters until encountering the same captured character, and replace with that second capturing group (the non-space characters that came inside the quotes):

```js
//number 1:
var rew = /(['"])(\S+)\1/g;
$('span').contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType === 3) {
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(rew, '$2');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
Hello 'world'.<br>
Hello "world".<br>
Bob's<br>
games' difficulty
</span>
```